# How to make Travis yml wait longer

Tags: python, timeout, travis-ci

I'm new at travis, using it for my project. In general I'm running tests that take more than 50 min in total and all I need travis to do is to check once in a while if the results appear. I can't make the test on travis since it run on a different machine.

I noticed Travis limits are `50 min` per job but there isn't any limit on the whole build. I have a python script checks the result once in a while, how can I run it for 2 hours in total? b.t.w it's ok for me to run it like 6 times in the build

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
I've just made 5 jobs each one is running for 45 min and the yml looks similar to:

```
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: first
      language: python
      python: "3.6"
      script: python3 -u script.py
    - stage: second
      language: python
      python: "3.6"
      script: python3 -u bad_script.py
    - stage: third
      language: python
      python: "3.6"
      script: python3 -u script.py
    - stage: fourth
      language: python
      python: "3.6"
      script: python3 -u bad_script.py
```